# проверка на упорядоченность двумерного массива java

Tags: java

```
public boolean isSortedDescendant(int[][] matrix)
```

Возвращает true, если все строки двумерного массива matrix строго упорядочены по убыванию, иначе false. Пустая строка считается упорядоченной. Разные строки массива matrix могут иметь разное количество элементов.

Знаю решение для одномерного массива, а вот как это реализовать в двумерном не понимаю.

Мое решение для одномерного:

```
if ((array.length == 0) || (array.length == 1)) {
    return true;
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] <= array[i + 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Подсказка: двумерный массив состоит из нескольких одномерных.

Comment: это я знаю, но как реализовать в коде не понимаю

Comment: Проверить каждый одномерный массив по очереди. Если хотя бы один из не упорядочен, то и двумерный неупорядочен.

Comment: можете пожалуйста написать пример кода на джаве?

Comment: Могу, конечно, но не буду. С чем конкретно у вас проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выделить предложенный код для одномерного случая во вспомогательную функцию.
Тогда декомпозировать задачу будет будет гораздо проще, имея реализованный функционал для подзадачи. Например, с такой сигнатурой:

```
public boolean isSortedDescendant(int [] array)
```

Тогда мы сможем организовать проход в функции верхнего уровня, возвращая false после нахождения первой несортированной строки. Например, так:

```
public boolean isSortedDescendant(int [][] matrix) {
        for (int [] array : matrix) {
            if (!isSortedDescendant(array)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
 }
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо добрый человек! Не смог допереть как использовать алгоритм от одномерного массива к двумерному..теперь понял)